# Hiring me just to fire me when transition is complete?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, employment

Some background: I work at *TargetCo*, *SourceCo* pays *MiddleCo* for my services at *TargetCo*, and my check is written by *MiddleCo* because they're an authorized *SourceCo* reseller.

For other reasons, I went job hunting. I recently received an offer from *AnotherCo*.

Once I give my two-week notice, chances are *SourceCo* will offer me full-time employment at *SourceCo*. The reason is that I do almost everything at *TargetCo* and two weeks simply is not enough time to transition properly.

My concern is that *SourceCo* could be offering me a job so that the transition takes place smoothly. But what happens after that?

For example, let's say it takes me a month to transition all the work to my TargetCo replacement, how can I be certain that they won't fire me once the transition has been complete?

Just to clarify, I've been working with SourceCo for over 10 years, and they've treated me well. They're a Fortune 500 company and they have many markets and many different job openings.

I'm just being cautious; if I accept SourceCo's offer, I'll have to reject the initial offer from AnotherCo.

Comment: Get a contract fi you're worried about getting fired after a transition.

Answer (score 14):

I wouldn't take the offer.  This is just taking a counter offer with more steps; and because the offering company knows you're unhappy enough to be looking will normally assume you'll still leave within a year and start looking for a replacement asap.

You might not get the offer from SourceCo you're anticipating.  Anti-poach agreements signed between companies in the setup you're in often preclude the customer hiring anyone from the provider for a period of time long enough to make waiting it out impractical on both sides.